# catchfilebetweentags error with multicol

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, catchfile

I am using the `catchfilebetweentags` library to store equations in an external file and then import them into my document. This is useful when you need to use the same equation in multiple documents. This works for simple equations, but introduces an offset error when used with the `multicols` package. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

### MWE

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\loadeq}[1] {
    \ExecuteMetaData[./equations.tex]{eq#1}
}

\begin{document}

Loading equations from external file:
\loadeq{001}

Local equations:
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{equ:X2}
        X = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            X_0 \\
            X_1 \\
            X_2 \\
            X_3
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
        \label{equ:Y2}
        Y = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            Y_0 \\
            Y_1 \\
            Y_2 \\
            Y_3
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

#### `equations.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

%<*eq001>
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{equ:X}
        X = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            X_0 \\
            X_1 \\
            X_2 \\
            X_3
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
        \label{equ:Y}
        Y = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            Y_0 \\
            Y_1 \\
            Y_2 \\
            Y_3
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
%</eq001>

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very nicely laid out example!

Comment: @egreg Thanks; do you know how to embed the latex output?

Comment: Just add a screen shot, I'll do it for you.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Looks like you got the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `catchfilebetweentags` ignores blank lines. If you remove the blank line in the “local” part, you get exactly the same.

Solution: use `\par` in the auxiliary file instead of a blank line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

%<*eq001>
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{equ:X}
        X = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            X_0 \\
            X_1 \\
            X_2 \\
            X_3
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\par
    \begin{equation}
        \label{equ:Y}
        Y = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            Y_0 \\
            Y_1 \\
            Y_2 \\
            Y_3
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
%</eq001>

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, using `multicol` to show equations side by side is not the best method, I'd go for two `minipage`s.

Comment: Why do a I need a space between the equations? I see that it makes a difference, but don't understand why.

Comment: @Napthali Actually, one should *never* have an `equation` environment immediately following a blank line or just after `\begin{multicols}`. That's why I suggest `minipage`.